# in jsp file, the "submit" button should use action="servletName" or use javascript/ajax to link to .jsp file itself?

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, submit

in a jsp file named something.jsp, there is a "submit" button:

I have seen 2 ways to use the submit button:
1. use < form name="xxx" action="servletName" /> to redirect the jsp page to a servlet.
2. use < input name="aa" value="submit" type="submit" onclick="processData('something.jsp','xxx','blah');" /> 
Notice that it uses javascript/ajax to renew data in the same jsp page. This jsp page redirects to itself. In this jsp page, there are lots of java code (I know,it's legacy code, old style). These java code will use jdbc to connect to database to query data. Then the jsp page will use .ajax to show data onto the same jsp page.

My question is: Which way is better? Which is more popular these days?

Answer (score 0):

`Which is more popular these days`?

Ajax. The perceived performance of AJAX is often greater because fewer HTTP requests are required to complete the user's action.

`Which way is better`?

Depends on your requirement. You cannot have Ajax when you want to Logout users, redirect to third party sites, navigating to a different domain of yours etc.

This link talks w.r.t [performance impacts of Ajax development](http://www.webperformance.com/library/reports/ajax-bandwidth-testing/).

Comment: Using ajax, I don't need to redirect my jsp file to servlet. Is this a popular way now? However, there should be NO java code (scriptlet) in jsp file. The second way uses java code and scriplet in the jsp file to achieve its goal.<br /> So, without java code and scriptlet in a jsp file, how to use ajax in a jsp file? Use the first way or the 2nd way?